# I can not determine if these events are independent. (Please check my work)

Tags: probability

I came across this question :

> A class consists of $80$ students, $25$ of them are girls and $55$ boys, $10$ of them are rich and the remaining poor, $20$ of them are fair complexioned. What is the probability of selecting a fair complexioned rich girl? Now consider the following events: $A =$ selecting a fair complexioned student, $B =$ selecting a rich student, $C =$ selecting a girl.

In the solution the required probability is given as $P(ABC)=P(A)P(B)P(C)$ and it is written that the events are independent.

But why are the events independent? Like if I consider the events $A$ and $C$, we can see that if $C$ occurs then the probability of occurrence of $A$ will change as it will not include the fair boys , so they should be dependent . I mean $P(A\mid C)$ is not equal to $P(A)$.

So how can they be independent ?

Comment: If $C$ occurs then you are only looking at girls, but is there any difference between the probability that a selected girl is fair complexioned ($P(A|C)$) and the probability that a selected student is fair complexioned ($P(A)$)?

Comment: @drhab  Yes P(A|C) and P(A) should be different because there can also be fair complexioned boys. And P(A|C) would mean that we are only considered about the girls which are fair complexioned.

Comment: Let's say that $11$ boys and $5$ girls are fair complexioned. Then the probability for a girl to be fair complexioned is $\frac5{25}=0.20$ right? It equals the probability for a student to be fair complexioned.

Comment: In the question that you encountered it is somehow taken for granted that things like gender, richness and being fair complexioned are unrelated.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually impossible for these events to be independent. If they were, the probability of selecting a fair-complexioned rich girl would be $\frac14\times\frac18\times\frac5{16}=\frac5{512}.$

However, this can't be the right answer. There are $80$ students in the class so this probability must actually be $\frac k{80}$ for some $k$. (There is not enough information given to determine $k$; it could be anything from $0$ to $10$.)

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad problem. You should *not* assume independence unless it is indicated, either explicitly or implicitly.  Here, it is contraindicated.

You cannot complete the problem with such an assumption, and the assumption does not hold. The events *cannot* be independent, because that would require there to be $3.125$ rich girls in the class.

$$\begin{array}{l|ll:l} & Girl & Boy & \\\hline Rich & 3.125 & 6.875 & 10 \\ Poor & 21.875 & 48.125 & 70 \\ \hdashline & 25 & 55 & 80 \end{array}$$